# Make a compreherenssion list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
from random import seed
from random import randint

print("How long list 1 do you want:")
long1 = int(input())
print("How long list 2 do you want:")
long2 = int(input())

print("in range 1-100","Generating 2 random list...", sep="\n")
list1 = [randint(1,100) for i in range(long1)]
list2 = [randint(1,100) for i in range(long2)]
print("List 1:",list1,"List 2:",list2, sep = "\n")
list = list1 + list2
unique=[]
for num in list:
    if num not in unique:
        unique.append(num)
print(f"Get unique number({len(unique)}) :", unique, sep="\n")
```

Above is the full code I already define the unique  but I want to make the loop simpler

```
for num in list:
    if num not in unique:
        unique.append(num)
```

I give it a try and make code like this:

```
unique=[num for num in list if num not in unique]
```

but it gives me an error message

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 21, in
>    File "", line 21, in  NameError: name
> 'unique' is not defined

Comment: if you want one line solution `unique.extend(list(set(unique)-set(list)))`, but using list comprehension in such way where `unique` is keep modifying each time will show you error each itme

Comment: Where do you think you defined `unique`?

Comment: The first code does *not* work perfectly; it exhibits the same error (if not on the same line).  Maybe you forgot to include something in your post?

Comment: Can't you simply do `unique = list(set(x))`. You dont need a list comprehension.

Comment: I don't know what the "set" function is but I going to learn it, I'm new about this, and also thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a list comprehension to create the list you're trying to use as a reference. In the expanded code, you set `unique = []` before you enter your loop, so *unique* exists, and you can add values to it WHILE you're in the loop. You can't do that in a list comprehension. You can't access the interim list while you're comprehending it.
(Ha... I think I just made up that language. :)

If you want a unique set of list items, you can use another native construct, called a `set`. It gives you a unique set of list items, but they will almost certainly be reordered. Something like this:

```
list3 = list(set(list1 + list2))
```

`list1 + list2` combines the two lists, preserving the exact order.  The `set()` makes the items unique (i.e. - removing duplicates), but it loses the original ordering. You would have to do something more clever to preserve the original order.

Also, you should not use a variable named `list`, as it is a Python native type, like `int`, `tuple`, etc.

Comment: oh, I see thank you bro, but is there any solution to make the loop 1 line code?

Comment: If you don't care about order, you can say list3 = list(set(list1 + list2)). I added that to my answer above.

Comment: I don't know about the "set" function before, very easy to get a non-duplicate number lol, now I feel dumb to ask that kind of question, thank you anyway :)